# Wordpress post filter

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

Apologies if this is too random a question, but im completely new to coding. For information, I am using a purchased theme which integrates with a wordpress plugin called "WP Car Manager".

There is a post filter built into a theme/plugin and I want to amend one of the fields to filter on a different field.

I have found the filter php files and whilst its easy enough changing the select values and the field label in the filter, I dont know how to get it to actually filter on the options I select.

Here is the original code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="wpcm-filter wpcm-filter-frdate">
    <label><?php esc_html_e( 'First Registration', 'carmen' ); ?></label>
    <select name="frdate_to" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'First Registration', 'carmen' ); ?>">
        <option value="0"><?php esc_html_e( 'First Registration', 'carmen' ); ?></option>
        <?php for ( $i = 2015; $i >= 1900; $i -- ) : ?>
            <?php
            if ( $i < 1970 && 0 != ( $i % 5 ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $i ); ?></option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Which I have amended to the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="wpcm-filter wpcm-filter-frdate">
    <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Tier', 'carmen' ); ?></label>
    <select name="frdate_to" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Tier', 'carmen' ); ?>">
        <option value="0"><?php esc_html_e( 'Tier', 'carmen' ); ?></option>
        <option value="1">Tier 1</option>
        <option value="2">Tier 2</option>
        <option value="3">Tier 3</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

Now, on the filter of course I see the different label and select options, but the filter is not filtering on these options. What is confusing me is that I dont see anywhere in the original code that states which field it is actually filtering on.

Apologies for my extreme newbie-ness and if there is any help to point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: You might have more luck with the experts over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok thanks for that ill give that a try

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your loop

```
for ( $i = 2015; $i >= 1900; $i -- ) :
```

The decremental index is going from 2015 to 1900, not 0, 1, 2... like you have on your new select field.

Answer (score 0):

pls use this code

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="wpcm-filter wpcm-filter-frdate">
        <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Tier', 'carmen' ); ?></label>
        <select name="frdate_to" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Tier', 'carmen' ); ?>">
            <option value="1969"><?php esc_html_e( 'Tier', 'carmen' ); ?></option>
            <option value="1968">Tier 1</option>
            <option value="1967">Tier 2</option>
            <option value="1966">Tier 3</option>

        </select>
    </div>
```

you are entered wrong option value.
loop is running in original loop from 2015  to 1900.not 0 to ...........